# Mongodb does $concat need a new index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database with millions of data. These datas contains names but I have two types of name

Datas with a given name (`denomination` key)

OR

Datas with a person name (`firstName` and `lastName` keys, I don't have a key that concatenates the two in datas)

I would like to create an API which search the query on given name AND person name

For that, I have to search the query on `denomination` key AND on concatened `firstName` `lastName` key

That's why I, firstly, concat `firstName` and `lastName` keys into `identity` key.

Then i would like make an aggregation to match my query on those two keys

```
aggregate([
 {$addFields:{'identite':{$concat:["$lastName",' ',"$firstName"]}}},
 {
   $match:{
     $and:[{
       $or : [
         {
           'denomination':toUpper(MySearchQuery])
         },
         {
           'identite':toUpper(MySearchQuery)
         }
       ]
     }
     /*Here, i'll be able to add more conditions*/
   ]
  }
 }
])
```

So my question was how to manage indexes in that case ? Did i have to index my concatened key (`identity` but it does not exist in my datas) and `denomination`. Or do i have to index `firstName`, `lastName` and `denomination`

And if you have a better solution to make my searh, I take it too

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check my answer right now, I guess it should be more helpful, and don't forget to mark it as solved or helpful if you appreciate it.

Comment: The only problem in ur last solution (add separated field) is it takes too long to add another field in collection, that's why i try to find a solution without adding any field, but I think I've understand how to apply your answer in my problem. I'll check it and mark my question as solved if it's good. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Oh and i forgot to precise. In my actual query i don't search exact names, i use $regex, i forgot to write it in my question

Comment: well, query search is much better than the reach by regexp from a performance point of view. So I guess it should help you more. Anyway, I am 99% sure, that there are no other strategies for increasing performance in an aggregate query except those, that I describe.

Comment: I've try your solution but it does not really work, but I think it's because i've poorly set up your solution and I didn't talk about others conditions. I'll update my question by adding more details

Comment: I added a bit more info, but unfortunately, there is no silver bullet in your case. You had have to sacrifice something for better performance. Combine and store additional fields or somehow find a way to separate user queries by each requested field.

Comment: I think i'll add the concaneted key in my datas. It will take longs but no choice. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, only the first `$match` stage will be improved with the index in `.aggregation` query. And in that case, you'll need to modify the query:

```
.aggregate([
{
  $match: {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
  }
},
...
])
```

and make a compound index for your collection like: `{ firstName: 1, lastName: 1 }`

You might wanna check this [article and especially Pipeline Operators and Indexes part](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes) from MongoDB docs.

#### UPDATED

According to your problem:

> *The problem is I'll not be able to separate firstName and lastName. It will be like a search bar where u put firstName and lastName in the same query. That's why I have to concat them*

There are various ways to achieve it. The best available way is using a [$text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) and [text search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/). I am using it daily on a production database with 100m+ docs.

Mongoose Text Index example:

```
YourSchema.index(
    {
    'firstName': 'text',
    'lastName': 'text',
  },
  {
    weights:
      {
        'firstName': 2,
        'lastName': 1
      },
    name: 'SearchQuery',
  })
```

This is an example of a text index for search in multiple fields.
But if you want to look for a combination of `Joe Doe` as `firstName & lastName` you also could use virtual fields (not sure for 100%) or add a separate field for text index, like:

Collection Schema

```js
{
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  // ++combinedName: string
}
```

and then add a separate text index for `combinedName` field.

#### UPDATED v2

Unfortunately, you can't use mongoose virtuals in your case, the best way scenario is making another field with `firstLastName` combined and adding a [$text query index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/) with proper weights (which actually supports language and case(in)sensitive search) to `denomination` and `firstLastName` fields as I described above.

Another relevant, but not MongoDB option is to store part of the collection in ElasticSearch.

Is the only way to avoid performance issues for user-search queries (where reaction time is sensitive and should be no more then 2s) and without rebuilding the whole schema.

You could also make it possible, if you are using mongoose driver for mongo, with `default` property, where you could predefine your `firstLastName` value from `this.lastName` and `this.lastName`, so you won't need to manually add it every time.

But of course, for a first time, you'll need to update the whole connection via cursor:

```
await YourModel
  .find()
  .cursor()
  //.sort(by proprery not sure)
  .eachAsync(async (doc) => {
     doc.firstLastName = `${doc.firstName} ${doc.lastName}`;
     await doc.save();
  })
```

or `updateMany` (but updateMany is long query and not so good controllable as cursor)

Comment: The problem is i'll not be able to separate firstName and lastName. It will be like a search bar where u put firstname and lastName in same query. That's why i have to concat them

Comment: Thank you for the provided info. That is still not a problem, I'll edit my answer once more and then you'll check it.